# Do Nする verbs require the する part with まで（に）?

Tags: grammar, particle-まで

There is a sentence in an exercise in the Speed Master N4 book:

> [引越しします]までにいらないものを捨てておいた方がいいですよ。

The expression in brackets should be put in the correct form. The keys state that the correct form is 引越しする. Can する be dropped? Or does Nまで（に）works only when N is an expression of time?

Comment: By the way, is it really 入らない in the example sentence, and not 要らない / いらない?

Comment: The exercise asks to put the expression, and thus the verb, in the right form. "Can I just omit it?" may be a valid thing to wonder for the example sentence, but omitting it will clearly not be the answer to the exercise.

Comment: @Kaskade It was an autocomplete typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also say 引越しまでに (noun 引越し + particle まで + particle に) , but it is often not thought as a form of verb 引越しする.

Comment: Is it also the case for other suru verbs?